# Помогите разобраться с Notification

Tags: android, уведомления

Всем привет, кода здесь нет, я хочу разобраться с уведомлениями для пользователей которые не используют в данный момент приложение.

Как сделать чтобы приложение выдавало в указанную дату и время уведомления, и после каждые 30 минут, или в зависимости от того как выбрал пользователь, показывало снова, до того момента пока он не выключит?

Comment: Рекомендую нажать на метку notifications, которую вы сами и добавили. Там много полезного.